# JPA update based on column name

Tags: java, jpa

I want to update value to a specific column entered by the user. Here are my codes, do anyone how to modify it to correct one?

```
public void updateValue(String value, String id, String ww){   
   Query q = em.createQuery("Update TableA e SET e.?1 = ?2 WHERE e.num = ?3");
   q.setParameter(1, ww); //since has many columns, user require to specific column to update
   q.setParameter(2, value);
   q.setParameter(3, id);
   q.executeUpdate();    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should go for criteria builder query for your case... if you are using JPA 2.1.. here is something you can should do

```
public void updateValue(String value, String id, String ww){  
    CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();

      // create update
      CriteriaUpdate<TableAEntity> update = cb.
         createCriteriaUpdate(TableAEntity.class);

      // set the root class
      Root e = update.from(TableAEntity.class);

      // set update and where clause
      update.set(ww, value);
      update.where(cb.equalTo(e.get("num"), 
          id));

      // perform update
      this.em.createQuery(update).executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping, but I already figure out how to do it, I just create simple String.                                                                                        String s = "Update TableA e SET e." + ww +  " = ?1"  + " WHERE e.num = " + id;                                                                                                                Then put in em.createQuery(s), that is working.

Comment: @ChongZhengLun do not EVER do that without making sure that the value you're adding with `+` is one of a pre-filtered list. What you're doing is a major security risk that can compromise your entire database.

Answer (score 1):

You asked

> **Updating one column based on predicates (and possibly more advance operations).**

**More detail and Clean practice**

The best practice for criteria base operations like updates is to use `javax.persistence.criteria` interfaces, like [CriteriaUpdate](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaUpdate.html) and using `where()` clause restriction upon predicates.

Further more with respect of your predicates and column types you can use [CriteriaBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html) api's for many operations and aggregations, like appending other columns or values to desired column (path).

```
CriteriaUpdate<T> criteriaUpdate = criteriaBuilder.createCriteriaUpdate(type);
Root<T> updateRoot = criteriaUpdate.from(type);
Path<String> path = updateRoot.get(update_column);
criteriaUpdate.set(path, 'some_value');
entityManager.createQuery(criteriaUpdate.where(...)).executeUpdate()
```

Note that the `some_value` could even be calculated with nested operations and aggregations with help of `criteriaBuilder` like

```
criteriaUpdate.set(path, criteriaBuilder.api(...));
```

Summarizing in your case it will look like below

```
CriteriaUpdate<TableAEntity> criteriaUpdate = builder.createCriteriaUpdate(TableAEntity.class);
Path<String> path = root.get("ww");
criteriaUpdate.set(path, value);
entityManager.createQuery(criteriaUpdate.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("num"), id) )).executeUpdate()
...
```